# Speeding up triple nested loop

Tags: r, loops, nested

This has to run for each test case. For 5000 test cases, I have run this code and it took 290 seconds. Same thing in java takes 0.5 sec. Can any of this be vectorized? Is there any other R kind of way of writing the inner loop?

`ode` is the 2d matrix which is updated in the code. `pyxixj` and `pyxi` are two matrices whose value I use to update `ode`.

```
noClasses <- 3
nOfAttr <- 40
ode <- matrix(1, nrow = 3, ncol = 40, byrow = TRUE)
ind <- c(0, 125, 251, 377, 498, 619, 740, 861, 982, 1098, 1214, 1330, 1446,
  1562, 1672, 1782, 1892, 2002, 2112, 2222, 2326, 2430, 2534, 2638, 2742,
  2846, 2943, 3040, 3137, 3234, 3331, 3428, 3525, 3614, 3703, 3792, 3881,
  3970, 4059, 4148, 4237, 4321, 4405, 4489, 4573, 4657, 4735, 4813, 4891,
  4969, 5047, 5125, 5199, 5273, 5347, 5421, 5488, 5555, 5622, 5689, 5756,
  5823, 5890, 5950, 6010, 6070, 6130, 6190, 6250, 6310, 6364, 6418, 6472,
  6526, 6580, 6634, 6681, 6728, 6775, 6822, 6869, 6916, 6963, 7003, 7043,
  7083, 7123, 7163, 7203, 7243, 7277, 7311, 7345, 7379, 7413, 7447, 7475,
  7503, 7531, 7559, 7587, 7615, 7639, 7663, 7687, 7711, 7731, 7751, 7771,
  7791, 7810, 7828, 7845, 7861, 7876, 7890, 7903, 7915, 7926, 7936, 7945,
  7953, 7960, 7966, 7971, 7975, 7978, 7980, 7981, 7991, 7998, 7999)
attrIndex <- c(0, 1, 4, 9, 14, 20, 26, 33, 41, 46, 52, 56, 63, 70,
  76, 83, 90, 96, 102, 106, 110:129)
x <- c(1, 1, 4, 3, 2, 1, 5, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 6, 6, 7, 6, 5, 6, 2, 4, rep(1, 20))
set.seed(340)
pyxixj <- matrix( rnorm(noClasses*9000,mean=0.5,sd=0.1), noClasses, 9000)
pyxixjopp <- matrix( rnorm(noClasses*9000,mean=0.5,sd=0.1), noClasses, 9000)
for (y in 1:noClasses) {
  for (xi in 1:(nOfAttr-1)) {
    if(is.na(x[xi])) next
    p <- attrIndex[xi]+x[xi]
    for (xj in (xi + 1):nOfAttr) {
      vxj <- x[xj]
      if(is.na(vxj)) next
      ode[y,xj] <- ode[y,xj] * pyxixjopp[y, ind[p] + attrIndex[xj] + vxj]
      ode[y,xi] <- ode[y,xi] * pyxixj[y, ind[p] + attrIndex[xj]  + vxj]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please comment when you down vote, it helps to improve the quality of the question.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but it'd help if you post some toy data for your variables in order to make your code sample *reproducible*.

Comment: This is not reproducible. Provide sample data, what you have and what you want to achieve. The way you present this here keeps everybody guessing.

Comment: I have added the required details to the question so that it would be more clear as suggested. Does it help? should I add anything? @vaettchen

Comment: The second line `for (xi in 1:()) {` is missing something...

Comment: sorry , i have corrected

Comment: `Error: object 'ind' not found`. Please check your code sample in a clean R session before posting.

Comment: I have corrected and checked the code, it is now ok. @Ferdinand.kraft

Comment: sorry for the trouble.

Comment: Note that `seq(along = noClasses)` is a vector of length one, equal to `1`... Are you sure this is correct? Only the first row of `ode` is modified.

Comment: you are right, it should be for (y in 1:noClasses) , corrected

Comment: can anyone give me some hints on possible optimization here , if possible?

Comment: The fact that same code is taking 0.5 sec in java is worrying me. If anyone can point out the bottle neck it would be great. Thank you

Comment: The code as posted above is executed in less than 0.5 sec on my low class laptop. Are you talking about executing it 5000 times? You have another, outer loop that runs through 5000 cases of ode?

Comment: ya.. there is another loop running 5000 times @vaettchen

Comment: Maybe you should say a little more about what you're actually trying to do here. You're trying to multiply various cells from one matrix by various cells of another matrix?

Comment: using pyxixj and pyxixjopp matrices I need to obtain ode matrix according to the equations in the inner loop , I would be happy to add more details :) @Thomas

Comment: Well, I think you can simplify a couple of things. (1) `p <- attrIndex[xi]+x[xi]` is always the same...it doesn't depend on the looping, so just calculate it once outside of the nested loops. (2) In your sample data `x` is never `NA`, so if it's never `NA` in your real data you could remove those tests as well. (3) I think you can easily replace your outer loop with an `*apply` variant since the inner loop is always storing into the row of `ode` that corresponds to rows of the input matrices.